# How to distribute and use a ruby gem as a git submodule in a Github repository?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, git-submodules

I need to distribute a dependency to my project – the markdown -> manpage converter [ronn](https://github.com/rtomayko/ronn) – with the project, as a git submodule. `ronn` requires gems `hpricot`, `mustache`, and `rdiscount`. I would like to distribute them with my project too, to provide a ready to run, 0-install, standalone tool.

Can be the ruby interpreter pointed to a local directory with a gem? In other words, if I add the `ronn` dependencies to my project repository as git submodules, then how can I make ruby interpreter and/or `ronn` notice and use them?

There is no problem with providing `ronn` this way – it has a `bin/` directory with the `ronn` executable and can be simply run without installing any gem.

Comment: A) Do the licenses of the projects in question allow for embedding like this? B) Why are you doing this? It's contrary to how Rubygems works. You can always use the [vendoring feature of Bundler](https://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_package.html) to package gem installers, which is better than packaging raw source. In other words: **Ship .gem files, not source**. C) If you do this your module will have an unexpectedly huge footprint and will conflict with any other installed versions of those gems causing bizarre errors and tons of hassles.

Comment: @tadman: Thanks for the tip about shipping gems. I've ended up using the `--install-dir` option for `gem` and then setting `GEM_HOME` before running the tool.

Comment: If you have a concrete solution for this you may want to add that as a self-answer to help others in the same situation. This feature of Bundler isn't used that often, but it's intended precisely for your use case.